# Adding annotations to PDF on iOS device programatically and viewing it

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, pdf, annotations

I have done a lot of searching for the past couple of weeks for meeting the requirement of my client, annotate the PDF. Lots of pointers but none of them work the way we want. So this question.

Requirement : I want to add notes on to a PDF, these notes should embedded to the PDF as annotations/note which should be viewable on the Desktops as well as the iPads.

We are developing an app, this is one of the biggest hurdles we are facing as of now. Can some one please help us?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert the pdf to some format that can be drawn on, like an image file. There might be libraries for this, if not then you can also do a screen draw capture. Then do whatever you need to for the drawing/typing with textboxes or `CGContext`. Once you're done with that define a `CGRect` that encloses your final image. Then call

```
CGContextRef ctx = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:tmpFile], &mediaBox, NULL);
```

Where `mediaBox` is the `CGRect` that encloses your image.

Just so you know, **SO is not a place where you post requirements and people will code them for you**. You need to show what you've done and ask a specific question. I hope I've been able to point you in a helpful direction.

Comment: Did i ask anyone to help me in coding? I asked for pointers and tips , if you understood otherwise then i can edit the question and specifically ask for tips.

Comment: Did you manage to do it? I am also trying something similar and I have already seen some free iOS PDF apps doing exactly what you mentioned in your question. Unfortunately there is not enough discussion on this topic to take you till the end. Can you share some inputs?

Comment: @iGameRam Sorry if I came across as unfriendly. We see a lot of "gimmetehcodez" questions that are phrased very similarly to yours. Normally good questions contain what the team is already doing or it asks for specific pointers. Your question looks like emails I get from customers. Hopefully this helped you.

Comment: @Dustin I am trying to achieve the same thing. So far, I have been able to use libharu for creating a pdf and adding annotations of link type, sticky notes type and jump to destination type. But the problem is libharu doesn't convert a pdf document into another. In my case I will be loading a pdf and taking user annotations on top and in the end creating a new pdf with embedded annotations which can be viewed on desktops. I am now stuck at scanning a pdf and regenerating it as a new pdf using libharu. I figured out the annotations part using libharu. Any pointers?

Comment: I haven't used libharu. If you have a question about that tool specifically, feel free to post a question.

Comment: @Dustin, basically I have a question about scanning a pdf with whitespaces, newline chars and Uppercasing of words preserved into an NSString or Char *

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Comments aren't meant to be used for asking questions.